# Python mailbox on large mbox datasets

Tags: python, mbox

I am using the python package mailbox, and I am trying to extract the messages and clean the data. I am running into the problem that for large databases, I can call the constructor with my sample file, but when I try to print any messages my program hangs. I assume it is because the file I am trying to read is over 7GB. How can I deal with this problem?

Answer (score 0):

Consider splitting the mailbox manually. The format is fairly easy to process (as long as you only need read-only access) by reading it line-per-line; and you can use the existing classes for the actual parsing of individual messages.

Look up the definition of the mbox format - lines beginning with "`From`" start a new mail. You *can* split the huge file at these markers, then use the `mailbox` package to read only one file at a time.